# How to customize NettyApplicationEngine in a koin-ktor project?

Tags: koin

Hi the vanilla ktor Netty config does not allow long URLs, you need to customize the HttpServerCodec buffer sizes. How do you get access to this in a koin-ktor application?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a crappy way. I changed to use own main which was basically a fork of Netty.EngineMain.

```
// Copy and paste of the io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val applicationEnvironment = commandLineEnvironment(args)
    NettyApplicationEngine(applicationEnvironment, { loadConfiguration(applicationEnvironment.config) }).start()
}

// Copy and paste of the io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain
private fun NettyApplicationEngine.Configuration.loadConfiguration(config: ApplicationConfig) {
    val deploymentConfig = config.config("ktor.deployment")
    loadCommonConfiguration(deploymentConfig)
    deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("requestQueueLimit")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
        requestQueueLimit = it
    }
    deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("shareWorkGroup")?.getString()?.toBoolean()?.let {
        shareWorkGroup = it
    }
    deploymentConfig.propertyOrNull("responseWriteTimeoutSeconds")?.getString()?.toInt()?.let {
        responseWriteTimeoutSeconds = it
    }
    // Allow long URLs to be accepted
    httpServerCodec = {
        HttpServerCodec(1048576, 1048576, 1048576)
    }
}
```